# C++ matrix class template

Tags: c++, templates, matrix

I am coding a matrix template class and the problem I am having is that the array is created and the values are filled but when I use the print() function, the array is empty again. Could anyone perhaps indicate what I'm doing wrong please?

data is defined as such:

```
T **data; 


template<class T> 
CMatrix<T>::CMatrix( int rows, int cols)
{
setRow(rows);
setCol(cols);

data = new int*[rows];
// Create matrix with dimensions given

for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
    data[i] = new int [cols];
}

for(int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
        data[i][j] = (int) i * j;
    }
}
}


template<class T> 
void CMatrix<T>::print()
{
int i,j;

for (i=0;i<4;i++)
{ 
for(j=0;j<4;j++)
{
    printf("%.1f    ",data[i][j]);
}
printf("\n");
}
}
```

Main function:

```
int main (){    

int rows =4;
int cols = 4;

CMatrix<int>* matrixOne= new CMatrix<int>(rows, cols);
matrixOne->print();

    return(0);
}
```

Declarations of template:

```
template<class T> 
class CMatrix

{
private:
    int row;  // number of rows
    int column;  // number of columns

public:     

    CMatrix(int rows, int cols);

    CMatrix(const CMatrix& data); //Copy constructor

    //Constructor taking an array of 16 elements
    CMatrix(T Matrix[16]);
    ~CMatrix();

    T **data; 
    void setRow(int r);
    void setCol(int c);
    int getRow();
    int getCol();

    //Subscript operators
    T& operator()(int row, int col);
    T operator()(int row, int col) const;
    void print();



};
```

Comment: did you copy a compiling code? What do you mean by empty??

Comment: Can you post your main function.

Comment: Please post a *complete*, *minimal* working example. Code fragments aren’t helpful.

Comment: The code compiles fine. Let me edit it to show you the main function

Comment: @UmNyobe by empty I mean that the data array is being populated but when I print it out, the matrix outputted is all 0s: 0000, 0000, 0000, 0000 and these are not the values I saved.

Comment: you have a `row` variable and a `rows` variable...

Comment: I corrected that but my output is still the same - somehow I'm losing the data stored

Comment: I'm wondering where is the declaration of `CMatrix` and whether you managed to declare `T **data` in the global scope O_o

Comment: I'll add all the declarations I have so you can see

Comment: I posted my answer before your last update.  Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would make sure you are using your data variable and your row and column variables in a class.  This is by no means the most complete version, but it compiles and runs fine.

Also make sure that you use "T" and not "int" in your constructor.  See the comments.

Note the two comments in the print function about using row and col instead of hard coding the values.

```
#ifndef CMATRIX_H
#define CMATRIX_H

#include <stdio.h>

template <class T>
class CMatrix
{
public:
    CMatrix( int rows, int cols)
    {
        setRow(rows);
        setCol(cols);

        data = new T*[rows]; // replaced "int" for "T"

        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            data[i] = new T [cols]; // replaced "int" for "T"
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                data[i][j] = (T) i * j; // replaced "int" for "T"
            }
        }
    }

    void print();
    void setRow(int r){row = r;}
    void setCol(int c){col = c;}
    T& operator()(int row, int col);
private:
    T **data;
    int row,col;
};

template <class T>
void CMatrix<T>::print ()
{
    int i,j;

    for (i=0;i < row;i++) // Here you used to have row hard coded to 4
    {
        for(j=0;j < col;j++) // Here you used to have col hard coded to 4
        {
            printf("%.1f    ",(float) data[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

// Recently added
template<class T> T& CMatrix<T>::operator()(int row, int col)
{
    return data[row][col];
}

#endif // CMATRIX_H
```

Here is the main.

```
#include "cmatrix.h"
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    CMatrix <float> m(4,4);

    m.print();

    // Recently added
    std::cout << m(1,1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much this worked. So all I had wrong was that the the data was public and not private? And some type casting?

Comment: @TamaraCaligari Yes, you are right.  I forgot to add comments for where I fixed those bugs, too.  I'll add those edits.  I generally let my IDE create the stubs for my classes.

Comment: Thanks again! :) The only problem I'm having now is when I overload the function operator:

template<class T> 
T& CMatrix<T>::operator()(int row, int col)
{
   return data[row][col];
}

This returns 0.0 :/